# How to create ProgressDialog without obscuring the background window

Tags: android, progressdialog

I've got a little problem. When I use the showDialog() method of my Activity, it generates a perfect ProgressDialog, but the activity on the background (as the dafault behaviour) and becomes darker.

How can I avoid the darkening of my activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```